# @material-ui/core and @material-ui/icons is installed but still showing error

Tags: reactjs

@material-ui/core and @material-ui/icons is installed but still showing error while rendering the page.[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysaIp.png)

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xivcE.png)

Answer (score 1):

I can see from the package.json and the errors log that you have installed **@material-ui/icons** (version 4 of material ui) but the components are requiring **@mui/icons-material** which is version 5 of material ui.

`npm install @mui/icons-material`

Here is the link with the documentation to install properly material ui version 5 https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/